# Getting crash in ios7 _UINavigationBarBackIndicatorView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7, uinavigationbar

The code below is working fine in ios6 but getting crashed in ios7. What is the reason i am  not getting. Below posting the code and the error message i am getting.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{   
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(showLoading) toTarget:self withObject:nil];

if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"isBannerShown"]) //-ive logic is applied 
{
    [self.adBannerView setHidden:YES];
    [self.adBannerView setDelegate:nil];
}

if([Manager getInt]==3)
{   
    Animation *objAnimation = [[Animation alloc]init];
    self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:objAnimation animated:NO];
}

[self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:NO];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"setting.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

btnRefresh = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btnRefresh setFrame:CGRectMake(280,9,33,31)];
[btnRefresh setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"refresh.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnRefresh addTarget:self action:@selector(btnRefreshPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
barButtonRefresh = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btnRefresh];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButtonRefresh;

[self createTable];
if(viewMessage)
{
    [viewMessage removeFromSuperview];
}

viewMessage= [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(6,8,307,screenSize.height - 110)];
[viewMessage setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[viewMessage setAlpha:.7];
[contentView addSubview:viewMessage];

[self createView];
[viewMessage setHidden:YES];
[contentView bringSubviewToFront:adBannerView];

float width = [Manager getImageWidth] ;
float height = [Manager getImageHeight];
count =0;

if(imgViewFullImage)
{
    [imgViewFullImage removeFromSuperview];
}
imgViewFullImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,width,height)];
[imgViewFullImage setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[imgViewFullImage setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];
[self.view addSubview:imgViewFullImage];
[imgViewFullImage setHidden:YES];

UIImageView *imgHeader = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,44)];
[imgHeader setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"connect-req1.png"]];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:imgHeader];

UILabel *lblHeader  = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80,8,200,30)];
[lblHeader setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[lblHeader setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
[lblHeader setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[lblHeader setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:19.0]];
[lblHeader setText:@"Connect Requests"];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:lblHeader];

 btnRefresh = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btnRefresh setFrame:CGRectMake(280,9,33,31)];
[btnRefresh setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"refresh.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnRefresh addTarget:self action:@selector(btnRefreshPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:btnRefresh];

[self createTable];
if(viewMessage)
{
    [viewMessage removeFromSuperview];
}

viewMessage= [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(6,8,307,screenSize.height - 110)];
[viewMessage setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[viewMessage setAlpha:.7];
[contentView addSubview:viewMessage];

[self createView];
[viewMessage setHidden:YES];
[contentView bringSubviewToFront:adBannerView];

}
```

**Error:**

> [_UINavigationBarBackIndicatorView setAlpha:]: message sent to
>   deallocated instance 0x10e43760

update : found crash.

```
case 4:
    {
        btnMoreSelected=NO;
        [Manager setInt:1];
        [tabBar setSelectedIndex:2];
        [imgMore setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"more.png"]];
        [imgMyConnection setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"connect-req-hover.png"]];
        [imgIceBreaker setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"my-ice-brkr.png"]];
        [imgSetting setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"settings-nav.png"]];
        [imgSearchView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"search.png"]];
        [imgSearchSeparator setHidden:NO];
        [imgSettingSeprator setHidden:NO];
        [imgIceBreakerSeparator setHidden:YES];
        [imgMyConnectionSeprator setHidden:YES];

    }
```

It is crashing here [tabBar setSelectedIndex:2];

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why viewMessage allocating twice else you are posted twice in the same set of lines codes. remove or alter anybody. i haven't edit this post..

Comment: @iDev app killing here when controller comes here second time. I am using tab bar controller to switch between tabs when i reach to this view controller second time it crashes here.

Comment: read clear my second comments

Comment: i did that still it's the same issue.

Comment: @iDev Please have a look at my update. i found the actual crash. can you please guide in that.